How do i use \raggedbottom in LaTeX
I'm encountering a lot of answers (to a question about LaTeX forcing fit page) that suggest using \raggedbottom. I've put that code in a line before \begin(document), but it just doesn't do anything to the documment. How do i use this code properly? I'm new to LaTeX.

Welcome to TeX.SX! LaTeX stretches the content of the page to fill it, and it's usually better to let it do. You need a document with many pages to see the effect of \raggedbottom.

you use it as you describe but maybe the document class you are using defaults to raggedbottom (eg article class) in which case it will have no effect. Always show a complete small document that shows the problem so people can debug it.

BTW: You should use \raggedbottom only, if you really need it. Often there are better solutions. Sometimes it is indeed the best, but usually not for books.

IMHO this is a XY problem. Instead of asking how to use \raggedbottom you should show a minimal working example that makes reproducible why you think, that \raggedbottom could be useful in your case and how you've tried to use it. This would not only help us, to explain, why \raggedbottom is not working in your case and maybe how to change this, but also if there are alternative solutions without \raggedbottom.

Perhaps your are using a class that defaults to \raggedbottom so you see no effect.
Choosing book example that defaults to flush botttom
\documentclass[a5paper,twoside]{book}

\usepackage{graphicx}
%\raggedbottom
\begin{document}

\section{aaa}
aaa

\begin{center}
  \rule{3cm}{2cm}
\end{center}

\section{bbb}
bbb 

\begin{center}
  \includegraphics[width=.7\textwidth,height=.7\textheight]{example-image}
\end{center}

\end{document}

Here the large non floating image does not fit on the first page, so in order to make the baseline of the last line of text be at the bottom of the page, the white space has to be stretched.

If you uncomment \raggedbottom the first page has the same amount of white space, but rather than stretch the space within the page, extra space is added at the bottom of the page.

Usually it's better to allow the image to be moved to make a better page break, which is why \includegraphics is usually used in a figure environment, which enables it to float.
